# cytoscape plots no not showing up in juypyter: Failed to load model class 'CytoscapeModel' from module 'jupyter-cytoscape'

Tags: dask, jupyter-lab, cytoscape, ipycytoscape

I am trying to plot a dask graph inside the jupyter lab. First jupyter asked me to install one of `ipygraphviz` and `ipycytoscape`. I wanted to try the latter. I installed `ipycytoscape` with `pip`, but then the widget was not showing up. I am a bit confused about all the different JupyterLab plugins available.

[image]

I count three in total, and I am not sure which one is the correct one. I tried `jupyter-cytoscape`. But only got another error looking like this:
[image]

I am not sure, if I installed the wrong jupyterlab extension or if something is wrong with the cytoscape installation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly it started working. I rebuild the jupyterlab a few times.

[image]